# Listing items from Ionic 2 Storage

Tags: angular, ionic2, storage

I have the below Home.ts which calls a service, ProductService.ts to get me a list of objects from Storage which I render on home.html.

```
export class HomePage {

  products;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private productService: ProductService, private storage : Storage) {    

  }

  ngOnInit(){           
    this.productService.fetchProducts();           
    this.products = this.productService.products;           
  }
}

export class ProductService{
  fetchProducts(){
      this.storage.get('products') // returns a promise which returns data or error
        .then(
          (products) => {
            products? this.products = products : this.products = [];                      
        })  
        .catch(
          err => console.log(err)
        );  
  }
}
```

The listing doesn't work and i get a blank page. But if I copy the code from the ProductService and paste it straight in home.ts it works (see below).

```
export class HomePage {
  products;

  ngOnInit(){

      this.storage.get('products') // returns a promise which returns data or error
        .then(
          (products) => {
                          products? this.products = products : this.products = [];          
        })  
        .catch(
          err => console.log(err)
        );                     
  }
}
```

I would like to have the code in ProductService. And I don't know why its working this way.

Answer (score 3):

`fetchProducts` is asynchronous, you should use the results inside a success callback that this function could take as parameter:

```
fetchProducts(success: (products: any[]) => void): void {
    this.storage
        .get("products")
        .then(products => callback(products || []))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

and then:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.productService.fetchProducts(products => this.products = products);
}
```

Other possibilities include to make `fetchProducts` return a `Promise` or `Observable` so that you can subscribe to it in your `ngInit` method.

Comment: Thanks Darin. But is there anyway I can hide all these subscribing to Promises, Observables etc. in the service and just return the object to home.ts? 

So I don't have to be concerned about how the retrieval is implemented in the service

Comment: One way to hide it would be to have your service function take a callback with the results parameter as shown in my answer. In this case you don't need to know about the specifics of `subscribing` or `then` the promise. All you need is pass a function which will be called when the asynchronous method completes taking the resulting value as parameter. Now if you are asking about writing synchronous code from the asynchronous function, then the answer is no - you'd better get accustomed with promised, observables and callbacks if you are going to write some serious angular 2 based code.